# How to fetch json reponse from guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am fetching an API response and I am finding it hard to get the Json response,

Here is the Exception message:
[image]

Here is the code base

```
 try{
            $client = new Client([
                "base_uri"=> $this->base_uri,
                'connect_timeout' => 10
            ]);

        $response = $client->request(
                        "POST",
                       "https://creditswitch.net/api/v1/". $this->airtimeURI, 
                        ['json'=>[
                            'loginId'=>$this->loginId, 
                            'key'=>$this->publicKey,
                            'checksum'=>$airtimeChecksum,
                            "serviceId"=>$this->airtimeServiceId[$data["network"]],
                            "requestId"=>Paystack::genTranxRef(),
                            "date"=> Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                            "recipient"=>$data["mobile_number"],
                            "amount"=>$data["amount"],
                            ]
                        ]);
        $response->statusCode();
    }

    catch(RequestException $ex){
        $message = $ex;
        dd($ex);

    }
}
```

When I then do then try to decode the message it gives a null as response :

```
    catch(RequestException $ex){
        $message = $ex;
        dd(json_decode($ex->getMessage()));

    }
```

Comment: Can you try dump the $ex variable which is Exception instance?

Comment: @Mesuti I did so, check the first screen shot

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I can't see your posted image but I solve to see the image via a proxy website. I looks like Authorization exception. I don't know how to do authorization to this API. Can you share the "creditswitch.net" API documentation link? Because I don't found any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need with headers send API key or  username-password

```
try{

            $client = new Client([
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Basic base64_encode('api_key'))
                 ],
                "base_uri"=> $this->base_uri,
                'connect_timeout' => 10
            ]);

        $response = $client->request(
                        "POST",
                       "https://creditswitch.net/api/v1/". $this->airtimeURI, 
                        ['json'=>[
                            'loginId'=>$this->loginId, 
                            'key'=>$this->publicKey,
                            'checksum'=>$airtimeChecksum,
                            "serviceId"=>$this->airtimeServiceId[$data["network"]],
                            "requestId"=>Paystack::genTranxRef(),
                            "date"=> Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                            "recipient"=>$data["mobile_number"],
                            "amount"=>$data["amount"],
                            ]
                        ]);
        return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    }

    catch(RequestException $ex){
        $apiResponse = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        return $apiResponse['message']
    }
}
```

Comment: The API does not require headers.

Comment: The authorization is in the checksum parameter

Comment: If your API is at the stage of development, then it may require a basic authentication

Comment: I didn't create the API, I am only consuming thus I follow what the documentation requires, and it does not require a headers. Any help on How I can fetch the message? thanks for helping I appreciate

Comment: I changed my answer, now the method returns a message during errors

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response from the exception by calling `$ex->getResponse()` and work with it as with usual response then.

```
} catch(RequestException $ex) {
    $message = $ex->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();
    dd($message);
}
```